# Is there any way to infer an Action type, or a full Action?

Tags: c#, types, action, type-inference

I find myself (too) often using a construct like the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    public TypeA ObjectA;
    public TypeB ObjectB;
    public TypeC ObjectC;
    public List<TypeD> ListOfObjectD = new List<TypeD>();

    public void DoSmth()
    {
        return SomeConstruct(
            /*...*/
            new Setter<TypeA>(a => ObjectA = a), // these are the
            new Setter<TypeB>(b => ObjectB = b), // things I'm trying
            new Setter<TypeC>(c => ObjectC = c), // to make shorter
            new Setter<TypeD>(d => ListOfObjectD.Add(d)),
            /*...*/
        );
    }
}
class Setter<T>
{
    public Action<T> Action;

    public Setter(Action<T> action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Is there any way for the Setter class to infer the type of the Action and create the standard `(T obj) => Member = obj` Action by only passing the Member in some way? I'm thinking of something like:

```
new Setter(ObjectA)
```

which of course is not valid syntax, but should give you an idea what I'm trying to achieve. I'm using this construct literally **hundreds** of time in my code, so the code 
saved by this small change would be tremendous.

---

**Edit:** Added the TypeD example. The part

```
new Setter<TypeD>(d => ListOfObjectD.Add(d))
```

can be simplified to

```
new Setter<TypeD>(ListOfObjectD.Add)
```

which is awesome because it cuts from the redundant code. If only `<TypeD>` could also be inferred it would be perfect. I'm looking for something like this for the others.

**@Lazarus** - basically the purpose is to return setters, so other objects can set certain members of the class (or it can do other stuff defined in the Action) without accessing the class itself, only the Setter object. The full list of reasons is long and convoluted, but the structuring of the program works like a charm and I doubt needs changing (the example of course is simplified and doesn't really make sense as is).

---

**Edit 2:** I found a good way to simplify things for List's:

```
static class SetterHelper
{
    public static Setter<T> GetSetter<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        return new Setter<T>(list.Add);
    }
}
```

Now I can just use this:

```
ListOfObjectD.GetSetter()
```

which works perfectly! why can't I do the same for T directly? I tried this:

```
static class SetterHelper
{
    public static Setter<T> GetSetter<T>(this T item)
    {
        return new Setter<T>(t => item = t); // THIS DOESN'T SET THE PASSED MEMBER
    }
}
```

Of course it won't work as intended because it will set item, but not the passed member. I tried adding `ref` as `(ref this T item)` but it won't compile :(... It would have been perfect.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't test this as I don't have Visual Studio installed on my Windows partition but could you do public void DoSmth(Object ObjectType) then typeof(ObjectType) to get the object type when you create it?

Comment: I'm missing something here, what is the objective of this construct? My experience is that when something becomes too complex then I've normally misunderstood the problem space and/or the language constructs. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain what this construct does and why.

Comment: My experience is that when people post examples they often remove extraneous code so they can focus on just the problem. Without the context it can be confusing to other programmers as to why they would even want to do this. Certainly it is useful to make sure you are solving a problem as efficiently as possible but I feel this goes into design. If the question isn't specifically about design then I just try to help them solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Oh, I've just read your last edit... maybe this could help you ? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653854/making-a-value-type-behave-as-a-reference-type-using-expressionfunct

Comment: Why don't you implement `GetSetter` as a normal method (not extention method), with `ref T item` as parameter.. You can shorten the names of the method and static class to avoid redundant typing. Actually, it is legal to have both a `Setter` static class and a `Setter<T>` class in the same namespace, so you could write `Settter.Get(ref Object A)`

Comment: @jdv: That was my initial thought as well, but then I remembered that you can't capture a `ref` parameter.  See http://ideone.com/XyTFV  But an expression tree captures all the required information, so I was able to use that in my answer.

Comment: @Mike Bethany - this is not a question of design, it's just about the problem at hand - to simplify a very often used expression.

Answer (score 2):

Best I can offer you is the following syntax:

```
Setter.For( () => ObjectA );
```

using this helper class

```
static class Setter
{
    public static Setter<T> For<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
    {
        ParameterExpression[] args = { Expression.Parameter(((e.Body as MemberExpression).Member as FieldInfo).FieldType) };
        Action<T> s = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(Expression.Assign(e.Body, args[0]), args).Compile();

        return new Setter<T>(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh... sounds similar to this answer --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653854/making-a-value-type-behave-as-a-reference-type-using-expressionfunct/3654096#3654096

Comment: @digEmAll: Yeah, it is similar in many ways.  Didn't see your link until I had it all hashed out in Visual Studio though.

Comment: Not exactly performance friendly, but thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have mentioned that... expression trees are efficient compared to reflection, but not compared to pre-compiled code.  Of course, once the delegate is created, it'll be just as fast, but the initial setup process is not.