# please explain lambda workings

Tags: python, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a lambda and what is an example implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373832/what-is-a-lambda-and-what-is-an-example-implementation)

Here is the code for a lambda (from Byte of Python):

```
def make_repeater(n):
    return lambda s: s * n

twice = make_repeater(2)

print twice('word')
print twice(5)
```

The output is this:

```
wordword
10
```

Can someone please explain how the lambda works in longform? how are `word` and `5` passed to `s` in the lambda function?

thanks.

Comment: Good job asking a better question than the "possible duplicate" question, but the first answer there is pretty awesome.

Comment: I think I'm going to get a mental stack overflow error from recursing into duplicate questions...

Comment: See [understanding-lambda-functions in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833228/understanding-lambda-functions?lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jake described already, your `make_repeater` returns another function with `n` being bound to `2` (this is called a [closure](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html)). So your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
twice = lambda s: s * 2

print twice('word')
print twice(5)
```

Which is in turn roughly equivalent to:

```
def twice(s):
    return s * 2

print twice('word')
print twice(5)
```

Which is in turn roughly equivalent to:

```
print 'word' * 2
print 5 * 2
```

So what you actually do is:

- evaluate the expression `'word' * 2`, which results in `'wordword'` (multiplication of strings is defined by Python as repeating the string the given number of times)
- evaluate the expression `5 * 2`, which results in `10` (this should not surprise you)

The fact that your lambda function doesn't care about the type of its argument and dynamically decides *at runtime* which method of multiplication is correct, is called [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing).

Answer (score 1):

The function make_repeater returns another function (the lambda).  In your example, the lambda function is assigned the name "twice".  The lambda has one argument, "s", and one "static" value, "n" - the "n" is defined when the lambda is created (in this case, it is assigned to "2").  The value for "s" is determined when the lambda is invoked - either "word" or 5.  word * 2 = "wordword" and 5 * 2 = 10.