# Closure Because of What it Can Do or Because it Does

Tags: functional-programming, closures

Ok, this is a bit of a pedantic question but I'd like to make sure I'm understanding the definition correctly. Is the closure moniker used to describe anonymous functions that ***can*** lift variables in the local scope (Whether they actually do or not) or only when they ***do*** lift variables in local scope?

In other words if an anonymous function has the ***ability*** to lift variables in its local scope (Because the language offers that capability) but doesn't, is it still considered a closure?

My understanding is that it is a closure only when local variables are lifted. But an anonymous function that doesn't (Even though it can) is not a closure. So not all anonymous functions are closures but all closures are anonymous functions.

Again, sorry for the pedantry, but these things gnaw at me. :)

Comment: As far as you ask and not teach, you're not pedantic for me ^^ (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedantic). This question also interest me!

Comment: Another way to look at it is that in a language that has closures, anonymous functions that do not lift local variables are likely still to be represented at run-time the same way real closures are, for the sake of uniformity. But now that you mention it, yes, people tend to use "closure" only when there's some variable capture.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Assuming you mean within the context of computer science...*

A closure is a first class function which captures the lexical bindings of free variables in its defining environment.  Once it has captured the lexical bindings the function becomes a closure because it "closes over" those variables.

*Note this means closures only exist at run time.*

For a function to be a closure is orthogonal to the function being anonymous or named.  You can create a language that allows you to define named functions to be closures.

Here is a "named" closure in Python:

```
def maker():
  count=[0]
  def counter():
    count[0]=count[0]+1
    return count[0]
  return counter
```

Comment: So if it doesn't capture local variables then its not "closing over" any variables and therefore its not a closure; that makes sense. Good point on only being closures at runtime. But I guess one could speak of it as being a closure in code if it will be a closure at runtime. Might not be ontologically correct but it is convenient to speak of it that way. Thanks for bringing up the point about how the concept of a closure is orthogonal to the concept of an anon function. I didn't even think about that, but that makes sense.

Comment: However (to throw in a monkey-wrench) in languages like Python and JavaScript, the *containing scopes* are bound, not just free variables. For example, consider the use of `eval` or `locals()` -- inside a branch, no less! What now? :-)

Comment: Python doesn't bind the scope. At the time you evaluate the `counter` definition, it creates a "closure cell" for each captured variable, and stores them in the `counter` function. `maker().__closure__[0].cell_contents` is a reference to the list that was bound to `count` at the time `counter` was defined. (It's also a bit confusing that Python sometimes uses "closure" to refer to the tuple of cells, rather than the function that holds them, but ignore that.) Meanwhile, `maker().__code__.co_freevars[0]` is `'c'`. That's how it knows that a reference to `c` is a `LOAD_DEREF` on cell 0.

Answer (score 6):

One great definition of a closure is defined in [lua.org](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html):

> When a function is written enclosed in another function, it has full access to local variables from the enclosing function; this feature is called lexical scoping. Although that may sound obvious, it is not. Lexical scoping, plus first-class functions, is a powerful concept in a programming language, but few languages support that concept.