# How does functools partial do what it does?

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying, functools, partial-application

I am not able to get my head on how the `partial` works in `functools`.
I have the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary):

```
>>> sum = lambda x, y : x + y
>>> sum(1, 2)
3
>>> incr = lambda y : sum(1, y)
>>> incr(2)
3
>>> def sum2(x, y):
    return x + y

>>> incr2 = functools.partial(sum2, 1)
>>> incr2(4)
5
```

Now in the line

```
incr = lambda y : sum(1, y)
```

I get that whatever argument I pass to `incr` it will be passed as `y` to `lambda` which will return `sum(1, y)` i.e `1 + y`.

I understand that. But I didn't understand this `incr2(4)`.

How does the `4` gets passed as `x` in partial function? To me, `4` should replace the `sum2`. What is the relation between `x` and `4`?

Comment: Simple answer: it doesn't! It's actually passed as `y`. Try adding the line `print(f'x: {x}, y: {y}')` to the top of `sum2` and you'll see, Check @MSK's answer below.

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Roughly, `partial` does something like this (apart from keyword args support etc):

```
def partial(func, *part_args):
    def wrapper(*extra_args):
        return func(*args, *extra_args)            
    return wrapper
```

So, by calling `partial(sum2, 4)` you create a new function (a callable, to be precise) that behaves like `sum2`, but has one positional argument less. That missing argument is always substituted by `4`, so that `partial(sum2, 4)(2) == sum2(4, 2)`

As for why it's needed, there's a variety of cases. Just for one, suppose you have to pass a function somewhere where it's expected to have 2 arguments:

```
class EventNotifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._listeners = []

    def add_listener(self, callback):
        ''' callback should accept two positional arguments, event and params '''
        self._listeners.append(callback)
        # ...
    
    def notify(self, event, *params):
        for f in self._listeners:
            f(event, params)
```

But a function you already have needs access to some third `context` object to do its job:

```
def log_event(context, event, params):
    context.log_event("Something happened %s, %s", event, params)
```

So, there are several solutions:

A custom object:

```
class Listener(object):
   def __init__(self, context):
       self._context = context

   def __call__(self, event, params):
       self._context.log_event("Something happened %s, %s", event, params)


 notifier.add_listener(Listener(context))
```

Lambda:

```
log_listener = lambda event, params: log_event(context, event, params)
notifier.add_listener(log_listener)
```

With partials:

```
context = get_context()  # whatever
notifier.add_listener(partial(log_event, context))
```

Of those three, `partial` is the shortest and the fastest.
(For a more complex case you might want a custom object though).

Comment: from where did u get the `extra_args` variable

Comment: `extra_args` is something that passed by the partial caller, in the example with `p = partial(func, 1); f(2, 3, 4)` it is `(2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: but why we would do that , any special use case where something has to be done by partial only and can't be done with other thing

Comment: @user1865341 I added an example to the answer.

Comment: with your  example , what is the relation between `callback` and `my_callback`

Comment: After `my_callback` is wrapped with partial it will mimic `callback`'s API and you may call `my_callback` wherever could call `callback`.

Comment: Sorry i am getting little bit . iam 70% clear but still not 100% clear. can you give some more code example for current scenario like u did before. . i get to the point that `partial(my_callback, context)(event, params) == my_callback(context, event, params)` but i am not able to get , how can we use that where `callback is reuired`

Comment: Well callback is not a function to be replaced, it's more of an API description. I've updated the example code to reflect some semi-real-life situation.

Comment: sorry for the trouble . can you tell me how the solution would look like for the other two options like `object creating` and lambda. i am not able to comprehend yet. i am new to python

Comment: @user1865341 I updated the answer with object and lambda solutions.

Comment: In your example:
>>> incr2 = functools.partial(sum2, 1)
>>> incr2(4)
Am i right in thinking, the 4 is extra_args, and 1 is part_args, so effectively the incr2(4) == sum2(1, 4)

Comment: @CanLu yes, or, more general, `partial(f, x)(y) == f(x, y)` for all `f`,`x`,`y`.

Comment: Does this perform any constant folding to achieve performance gains, like currying in functional languages?

Comment: @Brent I don't think so, that would require static analysis, while in Python types are unknows until the execution.

Comment: Good answer, though IMHO it's important to note the role of closures, as in ["Closures, Partials and Decorators"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055508/closures-partials-and-decorators).

Comment: This line seems like it should be deleted: `context = get_context()  # whatever`. It's not part of any of the other examples, and it adds an extra line to just the `partial` example which is omitted from all the other examples for some reason, kinda obscuring the fact that the `partial` example is actually just one line versus the two or more of the others.

Comment: Why not `return func(*part_args, *extra_args)`?

Comment: @The_spider good point. Back then in 2013 either it was not supported or I just missed it.

Answer (score 176):

**partials** are incredibly useful.

For instance, in a 'pipe-lined' sequence of function calls (in which the returned value from one function is the argument passed to the next).

Sometimes a function in such a pipeline requires a *single argument*, but the function immediately upstream from it returns *two values*.

In this scenario, `functools.partial` might allow you to keep this function pipeline intact.

Here's a specific, isolated example: suppose you want to sort some data by each data point's distance from some target:

```
# create some data
import random as RND
fnx = lambda: RND.randint(0, 10)
data = [ (fnx(), fnx()) for c in range(10) ]
target = (2, 4)

import math
def euclid_dist(v1, v2):
    x1, y1 = v1
    x2, y2 = v2
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
```

To sort this data by distance from the target, what you would like to do of course is this:

```
data.sort(key=euclid_dist)
```

but you can't--the *sort* method's *key* parameter only accepts functions that take a *single* argument.

so re-write `euclid_dist` as a function taking a *single* parameter:

```
from functools import partial

p_euclid_dist = partial(euclid_dist, target)
```

`p_euclid_dist` now accepts a single argument,

```
>>> p_euclid_dist((3, 3))
  1.4142135623730951
```

so now you can sort your data by passing in the partial function for the sort method's key argument:

```
data.sort(key=p_euclid_dist)

# verify that it works:
for p in data:
    print(round(p_euclid_dist(p), 3))

    1.0
    2.236
    2.236
    3.606
    4.243
    5.0
    5.831
    6.325
    7.071
    8.602
```

Or for instance, one of the function's arguments changes in an outer loop but is fixed during iteration in the inner loop. By using a partial, you don't have to pass in the additional parameter during iteration of the inner loop, because the modified (partial) function doesn't require it.

```
>>> from functools import partial

>>> def fnx(a, b, c):
      return a + b + c

>>> fnx(3, 4, 5)
      12
```

create a partial function (using keyword arg)

```
>>> pfnx = partial(fnx, a=12)

>>> pfnx(b=4, c=5)
     21
```

you can also create a partial function with a positional argument

```
>>> pfnx = partial(fnx, 12)

>>> pfnx(4, 5)
      21
```

but this will throw (e.g., creating partial with keyword argument then calling using positional arguments)

```
>>> pfnx = partial(fnx, a=12)

>>> pfnx(4, 5)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#80>", line 1, in <module>
      pfnx(4, 5)
      TypeError: fnx() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

another use case: writing distributed code using python's `multiprocessing` library. A pool of processes is created using the Pool method:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as MP

>>> # create a process pool:
>>> ppool = MP.Pool()
```

`Pool` has a map method, but it only takes a single iterable, so if you need to pass in a function with a longer parameter list, re-define the function as a partial, to fix all but one:

```
>>> ppool.map(pfnx, [4, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: is there any practical use of this function somewher

Comment: @user1865341 added two exemplarly use cases to my answer

Comment: IMHO, this is a better answer as it keeps out unrelated concepts like objects and classes and focuses on functions which is what this is all about.

Answer (score 87):

short answer, `partial` gives default values to the parameters of a function that would otherwise not have default values.

```
from functools import partial

def foo(a,b):
    return a+b

bar = partial(foo, a=1) # equivalent to: foo(a=1, b)
bar(b=10)
#11 = 1+10
bar(a=101, b=10)
#111=101+10
```

Comment: this is half true because we can override default values, we can even override overriden parameters by subsequent `partial` and so on

Comment: First, he did not claim they are immutable and secondly, he even demonstrates how they can be overridden?

Answer (score 57):

Partials can be used to make new derived functions that have some input parameters pre-assigned

To see some real world usage of partials, refer to this really good blog post [here](http://chriskiehl.com/article/Cleaner-coding-through-partially-applied-functions/)

A simple but neat beginner's example from the blog, covers how one might use `partial` on `re.search` to make code more readable.   `re.search` method's signature is:

```
search(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

By applying `partial` we can create multiple versions of the regular expression `search` to suit our requirements, so for example:

```
is_spaced_apart = partial(re.search, '[a-zA-Z]\s\=')
is_grouped_together = partial(re.search, '[a-zA-Z]\=')
```

Now `is_spaced_apart` and `is_grouped_together` are two new functions derived from `re.search` that have the `pattern` argument applied(since `pattern` is the first argument in the `re.search` method's signature).

The signature of these two new functions(callable) is:

```
is_spaced_apart(string, flags=0)     # pattern '[a-zA-Z]\s\=' applied
is_grouped_together(string, flags=0) # pattern '[a-zA-Z]\=' applied
```

This is how you could then use these partial functions on some text:

```
for text in lines:
    if is_grouped_together(text):
        some_action(text)
    elif is_spaced_apart(text):
        some_other_action(text)
    else:
        some_default_action()
```

You can refer the [link](http://chriskiehl.com/article/Cleaner-coding-through-partially-applied-functions/) above to get a more in depth understanding of the subject, as it covers this specific example and much more..

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `is_spaced_apart = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]\s\=').search`? If so, is there a guarantee that the `partial` idiom compiles the regular expression for faster reuse?

Comment: Commenting because edit queue is full. The link is dead. It can be replaced with https://web.archive.org/web/20160920124126/https://chriskiehl.com/article/Cleaner-coding-through-partially-applied-functions/

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion, it's a way to implement [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in python.

```
from functools import partial
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

def add2number(x,y,z):
    return x + y + z

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add2 = partial(add,2)
    print("result of add2 ",add2(1))
    add3 = partial(partial(add2number,1),2)
    print("result of add3",add3(1))
```

The result is 3 and 4.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. Currying is dividing a function with n parameters into n successive functions with one parameter. Partial application is 'pre-filling' a function with some parameters, then returning a function with a smaller number of parameters

Answer (score 4):

This answer is more of an example code. All the above answers give good explanations regarding why one should use partial. I will give my observations and use cases about partial.

```
from functools import partial
 def adder(a,b,c):
    print('a:{},b:{},c:{}'.format(a,b,c))
    ans = a+b+c
    print(ans)
partial_adder = partial(adder,1,2)
partial_adder(3)  ## now partial_adder is a callable that can take only one argument
```

Output of the above code should be:

```
a:1,b:2,c:3
6
```

Notice that in the above example a new callable was returned that will take parameter (c) as it's argument. Note that it is also the last argument to the function.

```
args = [1,2]
partial_adder = partial(adder,*args)
partial_adder(3)
```

Output of the above code is also:

```
a:1,b:2,c:3
6
```

Notice that * was used to unpack the non-keyword arguments and the callable returned in terms of which argument it can take is same as above.

*Another observation is:*
Below example demonstrates that partial returns a callable which will take the 
undeclared parameter (a) as an argument.

```
def adder(a,b=1,c=2,d=3,e=4):
    print('a:{},b:{},c:{},d:{},e:{}'.format(a,b,c,d,e))
    ans = a+b+c+d+e
    print(ans)
partial_adder = partial(adder,b=10,c=2)
partial_adder(20)
```

Output of the above code should be:

```
a:20,b:10,c:2,d:3,e:4
39
```

Similarly,

```
kwargs = {'b':10,'c':2}
partial_adder = partial(adder,**kwargs)
partial_adder(20)
```

Above code prints

```
a:20,b:10,c:2,d:3,e:4
39
```

I had to use it when I was using `Pool.map_async` method from `multiprocessing` module. You can pass only one argument to the worker function so I had to use `partial` to make my worker function look like a callable with only one input argument but in reality my worker function had multiple input arguments.

Comment: Would `Pool.starmap_async` have worked for you?

Comment: I think it would've!

Answer (score 3):

Also worth to mention, that when partial function passed another function where we want to "hard code" some parameters, that should be rightmost parameter

```
def func(a,b):
    return a*b
prt = partial(func, b=7)
    print(prt(4))
#return 28
```

but if we do the same, but changing a parameter instead

```
def func(a,b):
    return a*b
 prt = partial(func, a=7)
    print(prt(4))
```

it will throw error, 
    "TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'a'"

Comment: Huh?  You do the leftmost parameter like this: `prt=partial(func, 7)`

Answer (score 3):

Adding couple of case from machine learning where the functional programming **currying** with `functools.partial` can be quite useful:

**Build multiple models on the same dataset**

the following example shows how `linear regression`, `support vector machine` and `random forest` regression models can be fitted on the same `diabetes` dataset, to predict the target and compute the score.

The (partial) function `classify_diabetes()` is created from the function `classify_data()` by currying (using `functools.partial()`). The later function does not require the data to be passed anymore and we can straightaway pass only the instances of the classes for the models.

```
from functools import partial
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

def classify_data(data, model):
    reg = model.fit(data['data'], data['target'])
    return model.score(data['data'], data['target'])

diabetes = load_diabetes()
classify_diabetes = partial(classify_data, diabetes) # curry
for model in [LinearRegression(), SVR(), RandomForestRegressor()]:
    print(f'model {type(model).__name__}: score = {classify_diabetes(model)}')

# model LinearRegression: score = 0.5177494254132934
# model SVR: score = 0.2071794500005485
# model RandomForestRegressor: score = 0.9216794155402649
```

**Setting up the machine learning pipeline**

Here the function `pipeline()` is created with currying which already uses `StandardScaler()` to preprocess (scale / normalize) the data prior to fitting the model on it, as shown in the next example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipeline = partial(make_pipeline, StandardScaler()) # curry    
for model in [LinearRegression(), SVR(), RandomForestRegressor()]:
    print(f"model {type(model).__name__}: " \
          f"score = {pipeline(model).fit(diabetes['data'], diabetes['target'])\
                                 .score(diabetes['data'], diabetes['target'])}")

# model LinearRegression: score = 0.5177494254132934
# model SVR: score = 0.2071794500005446
# model RandomForestRegressor: score = 0.9180227193805106
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wondering how the `partial` function works, consider the implementation of the `my_partial` function, which has the same functionality as the `functools.partial` function:

## my_partial function

```
def my_partial(func, *_args, **_kwargs):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*(_args + args), **dict(_kwargs, **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

The `my_partial` function takes `func` as an argument along with `*_args` (list arguments) and `**_kwargs` (keyword arguments). Using `_args` and `_kwargs`, we can fix initial arguments to the `my_partial` function along with a function.

Inside the `my_partial` function, we have another function, `wrapper`. When the outer function(`my_partial`) is called with a function as an argument with some optional arguments, we return the `wrapper` function, which also takes list arguments and keyword arguments.

Since both `my_partial` and `wrapper` functions are taking arguments this way, we can pass arguments to our function twice. First, we call `my_partial` and pass a function with optional arguments, and then the `my_partial` function returns the `wrapper function` which also takes option arguments. This way we can pass arguments twice.

The `wrapper` function combines positional arguments that are passed to `my_partial` with its arguments. The `wrapper` function calls the function (`func`) that was passed as an argument to `my_partial`.

In wrapper, we return `func(*(_args + args), **dict(_kwargs, **kwargs))`. Here, `_args` and `args` are both `tuples`, and `+` is the concatenation operator, which combines elements from `_args` and `args`. Notice we have mentioned `_args` before `args` because `_args` has the arguments passed to `my_partial`, and since it was passed first, we must have it first. Here, `dict(**_kwargs, **kwargs)` combines two dictionaries into a single dictionary.

## Use Case:

Often, a function might need many arguments, and suppose we have to use that function repeatedly. In that case, we can wrap the function with `partial`, specifying fixed arguments that we may have to pass multiple times to the function.

```
from functools import partial

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

double = partial(multiply, 2)

print(double(10))
```

Output:

```
20
```

Notice in the above statement, `partial(multiply, 2)`, we are specifying that the argument a in `multiply` will be 2. So, when we have to double a value, we need not pass the value 2 to the multiply function multiple times.

This was indeed a simple function (`multiply`), but often there might be situations where we have to pass many arguments to a function. In that case, we can use partial to specify the arguments that we may have to pass multiple times.