# Do all callables have __name__?

Tags: python

I have a decorator that logs the name of the decorated function (among other things).

Is it safe to access the `__name__` attribute of the decorated function? Or is there some callable type that doesn't have name that I have not run into yet?

Comment: Not always! Note partial objects not creates `__name__` attribute

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Answering my own question with a summary of other answers and comments.

Not all callables have `__name__`.

- Instances of classes that define `__call__` may not have a `__name__` attribute.
- Objects created with `functools.partial` do not have a `__name__` attribute.

A workaround is to use the three argument `getattr`:

```
name = getattr(callable, '__name__', 'Unknown')
```

Or use `repr(callable)` instead of `'Unknown'`, which would include more information about the callable:

```
name = getattr(callable, '__name__', repr(callable))
```

Answer (score 10):

It is pretty safe with functions:

```
def d():
    pass

l = lambda: None
print(d.__name__)
print(l.__name__)
```

Output:

```
> d 
> <lambda>
```

You can even safely modify it (for debuging purposes as an example):

```
l.__name__ = 'Empty function'
print(l.__name__)  # Empty function
```

But beware of classes with `__call__` method, they don't have a `__name__` attribute.

```
class C(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print('call')

print(C().__name__)  # AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

#### Updated

As @felipsmartins pointed out in comments, [`functools.partial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python) also doesn't have `__name__` attribute. [Partial Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) refer to the original function with the member variable `func` which let's you get the original function's name like so:`my_partial.func.__name__`.

Related:

[What is a "callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

Comment: Also, note partial objects not creates `__name__` attribute.

Comment: Of course, you can just ignore the issue by using three-arg `getattr`: `getattr(callable, '__name__', 'Unknown')` will avoid exceptions and give you some output. Alternatively, `getattr(callable, '__name__', repr(callable))` gets you a more tailored `repr` version (which should help with instances whose class implements `__call__`.