# Bind method to object runtime late binding

Tags: python, functools, lexical-closures

I am aware about late bindings in loop in python, but I cant find way to solve this .

```
def bind_method(object, methods):

    for method in methods:
        def my_method():
            result = method()

            return result

        setattr(object, method.__name__, my_method)

def test():
    class A: pass

    def bar(): 
        return "BAR"

    def foo(): 
        return "FOO"

    a = A()
    bind_method(a, [bar, foo])

    assert a.foo() == "FOO"
    assert a.bar() == "BAR"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

I tried with `partial` in `functools` but not get success :(

Comment: @AKS typo error :( correct the post

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `a.bar()` `my_method` is invoked and since the for loop has ended the value of `method` for it is the last element in `methods` list so you always get `"FOO"` as result.

To check you can add a print statement:

```
def my_method():
    print(method.__name__) # this will always print `foo`
    result = method()
```

But when I set it directly:

```
def bind_method(object, methods):
    for method in methods:
        setattr(object, method.__name__, method)
```

It does work.

---

**Using `functools.partial`**:

```
from functools import partial

def bind_method(object, methods):

    for method in methods:
        def my_method(a_method):
            print(a_method.__name__) # this print correct method name
            result = a_method()
            return result

        setattr(object, method.__name__, partial(my_method, method))
```

Comment: Its working now, but how it works with partial? if you explain then it helps to understand this concept.

Comment: It is already explained here: [How does the functools partial work in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python)