# Closures, Partials and Decorators

Tags: python

I am confused between the three. I understand that closures are functions returned by another functions and have access to the local variables form an enclosing scope

example:

```
def add_nums(one):
    def adder(two):
        return one+two
    return adder

a_10 = add_nums(10)
print a_10(5)
15
```

Here, `adder` is a closure.

But, is this also not an example of a `partial`

```
from functools import partial
a_10 = partial(add_nums, 10)
print a_10()(5)
15
```

What is the difference between the two?

Also, decorators are used to add functionality to functions.

```
def add_nums(one):
    def adder(two):
        print "foo, bar"
        return one+two
    return adder

a_10 = add_nums(10)
print a_10(5)
foo, bar
15
```

What is the difference between all the three?

Comment: A decorator is just a function that takes a function and returns a function. As this often involves nested functions, it's common to access the argument function via the closure, where the inner function captures its environment, but I suppose you could implement that with a partial instead, where the values are passed in explicitly. It's not clear quite what you'd like to know.

Comment: Underrated question, and underrated answers. Thanks!

Comment: I literally thought of a very similar question before googling it and came across your post.  My thought was "Why didn't Python name 'partial' instead of 'closure'?" thinking that it would be more precise but knowing the implementation was specifically taking some scoped value. Functions being 1st class objects in Python thus the same as any other variable.  So as the answers below make clear its implementation a level deeper than the mechanism itself.

Answer (score 13):

I think you're confusing *purpose* with *implementation.* Creating a closure is a technique for doing things. You can do a bunch of things with closures.

On the other hand, `partial` and `decorator` are particular purposes. Maybe they use closures. Maybe they don't. That's an implementation detail, and you don't need to worry about it. What's important is that they achieve the result you want.

Consider a `partial`. (Ignoring **kwargs.) One way to create it would be to use a closure:

```
def partial(f, *args):
    def pf(*rest):
        return f(*args, *rest)
    return pf
```

But it doesn't have to be that way. For example:

```
class Partial:
    def __init__(self, func, args):
        self.args = args
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *rest):
        f = self.func
        args = self.args
        return f(*args, *rest)

def partial(f, *args):
    return Partial(f, args)
```

There's no closure here, just a variable that holds a reference to the other variables. But I get the partial behavior, so who cares?

The same is true for decorators. A decorator might be a closure, or it might not. For example, one recent question involved running `str.format` on a function's `__doc__` strings. That was just a case of accepting a function object, modifying the `__doc__` attribute, and returning the same object. Clearly, there's no closure involved in that.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer:  *closure* is the mechanism, while `functools.partial` and decorators are typical uses of that mechanism.

The key difference between a closure and more typical namespaces is that the names and values in the "closed-over" namespace don't vanish when control flow leaves the top-level function.  They're preserved in a mini-namespace associated with one instance of the inner function, and which survives as long as that instance does.

`functools.partial` uses that ability to "remember" some arguments to a pre-existing function.  Decorators also typically use that ability for the same reasons.

Note that a decorator is more flexible than that.  Any callable that takes one parameter and returns something can serve as a decorator.  It doesn't *have* to make use of Python closures, or even return a function.  Many decorators return a callable object instead.  (As an aside, a closure and inner function can be simulated using an object for the namespace and a method for the inner function.)

Whatever the decorator returns is assigned to the name the decorated function *would have* had.  (Decorators with parentheses after them, like `@decorator('args') ...` are slightly more complicated.)  The typical decorator syntax:

```
@decorator
def function():
    pass
```

...is just a shorthand for "define, then decorate and reassign":

```
def function():
    pass
function = decorator(function)
```

For an extreme (and mostly useless) example:

```
def decorator5(__):
   return 5

@decorator5
def square(x):
    return x * x

print(square)  # Prints 5 --- the function is gone.
square(10)     # TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

The partial version of your decorator would actually be:

```
def add_nums(one):
    def adder(one, two):
        return one + two
    return partial(adder, one)
```

Note that the nested function now *only* uses explicit parameters, *not* the closure. You can implement a decorator, which is just a function that takes a function and returns a (usually different) function, using either closures, `partial` (which is [implemented using a closure](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/functools.py#l235)) or a mix of the two.

Comment: You refer to closure as a thing. What exactly is a closure, in your words?

Comment: A closure is the environment available to the function, when it is called, on the basis of where it was created. Note that in your closure version the inner function can access `one` implicitly, not as an explicit parameter or a global variable, *because it was available where the function was created*.