# Standard deviation of predictive distribution of query points using a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to do a simple regression task using a pipeline to assign the degree of the polynomial used for the regression (degree = 3). So I define:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(3), BayesianRidge())
```

And then the fitting:

```
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And finally the prediction bit:

```
y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

BayesianRidge() of the sklearn has a `return_std` parameter for its **predict** method that when set to True, it returns standard deviation of predictive distribution of query points.

Is there anyway that I can get this standard deviation array using a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the latest version of scikit-learn from [their github repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn). Next you would simply need to use [partial  from functools](https://www.pydanny.com/python-partials-are-fun.html). I have used the example similar to the one mentioned in [Bayesian Ridge Regression docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#bayesian-ridge-regression).

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from functools import partial

clf = linear_model.BayesianRidge()

#Make the pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(3), clf)

#Patch the predict function of the classifier using partial
clf.predict = partial(clf.predict,return_std=True )

#Fit the pipeline
pipe.fit([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])

#Retrieve the prediction and standard deviation
y_pred, y_std = pipe.predict([[1,2]])
#Output : (array([ 1.547614]), array([ 0.25034696]))
```

**Note :** Apparently this was a bug in sklearn's pipeline module as [described here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9293). It is now fixed in the latest version.

Reference:

- [How partial works in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python)