# begin Q for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use tk to do this: [image]

Left text and Right button in one row,text data store in a list,so i use loop:

```
  for file in listname:
    fr = Frame(app)
    Label(fr,text = file).grid(row =row,column=0)
    Button(fr,text = 'download',command =lambda: download(file)).grid(row = row,column=3)
```

But when I click one button,the parm is always the last elem in list,so what can I do to create button with different parm in one loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda is not correct.

```
 import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

listname = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']


def download(file):
    print(file)


win = tk.Tk()
fr = tk.Frame(win)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0)
for row, file in enumerate(listname):
    tk.Label(fr, text=file).grid(row=row, column=0)
    tk.Button(fr, text='download',
              command=lambda f=file: download(f)).grid(row=row, column=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: No Problem xu yang

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lambda, try using partial. Include `from functools import partial` at the top of your code, and replace all calls like

```
lambda: download(file)
```

with

```
partial(dowload, file)
```

The link below should explain to you why this works.

[How does the functools partial work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python)