# Rename dataframe columns with a mapper function that takes parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I pass along parameters to a mapper function in [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)? The example below uses a mapper function `test`. I want to change it's behavior based on an additional parameter that I pass along.

```
def test(x):
    return "A" + x

df.rename(mapper=test, axis='columns')
```

In this example, the mapper function appends an `"A"` to each column name. I want the mapper not always to append an `"A"` but a character that I give as parameter in the function call. So my question is: how can I pass along additional parameters to the function `test`?

Comment: You could probably use [`functools.partial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python). Please include a [mcve] with a small sample input dataframe and the desired output.

Comment: I added the mapper function. How do I need to change the mapper function and the call so that it appends "A" in one case and "B" in the other case

Comment: It's still not clear what your desired output is. Do you want to add `"A"` to each column? Or `"A" + x`? [How to create good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: The mapper appends an "A" to each column name. I want the mapper not always to append an "A" but a character that I give as parameter in the function call. So my question is: how can I pass along a parameter to the function "test"

Comment: try add_prefix :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `functools.partial`:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

print(pd.__version__)
#0.23.4

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a', 'b', 'c'], "col2": [1, 2, 3]})

def test(col, x):
    return x + col

df.rename(mapper=partial(test, x="abc_"), axis='columns')
#  abc_col1  abc_col2
#0        a         1
#1        b         2
#2        c         3
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a custom `test` function, you can also use the built-in `lambda` function as the mapper function and pass parameters to rename dataframe columns in [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)
#1.4.2

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a', 'b', 'c'], "col2":[1,2,3]})

df.rename(mapper=lambda x: "abc_"+x,axis='columns')
#  abc_col1  abc_col2
#0        a         1
#1        b         2
#2        c         3
```

Comment: That is not what the OP has asked for.

Comment: This works for the OP's use case if "abc_" is replaced with the prefix the OP requires. E.g. `prefix = "A"`, `df.rename(mapper=lambda x: prefix+x,axis='columns')`.