# Subtyped function with reduced parameters?

Tags: python, function

Can I create a python function that is a subset of a different function, meaning I specify some, but not all of the parameters?

For example, here is some incorrect code illustrating what I'm looking for:

```
def foo(x, a, b):       # generic function
    return a * x + b

bar = foo(a=1., b=2.)   # create some specific functions
baz = foo(a=6., b=9.)   # that specify some of the parameters

bar(x=1)                # returns 3, can be used without tracking a,b
baz(x=1)                # returns 15
```

I'm nearly certain this is possible (the syntax is obviously wrong), but I can't remember the terminology to google it. Is it possible? What is the terminology and syntax for it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: partially applied function

Comment: `functools.partial` is what you are looking for. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331967/4932316) answer specifically in the Dupe