# Optional argument decorator

Tags: python

Can you explain to me how the partial function is working here?

```
def debug(func=None, *, prefix=''):
    if func is None:
        return partial(debug, prefix=prefix)
    msg = prefix + func.__name__
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(msg)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does functools partial do what it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does)

Comment: Not really, I understand how partial works. But I don't get how we are accessing the body of the function after the partial return.

Answer (score 1):

The `debug` function is designed so that it can optionally be called with the `prefix` keyword-only argument if you want, when you apply it as a decorator:

```
@debug(prefix="foo"):  # calling debug with a prefix works
def foo():
    pass

@debug                 # skipping the call also works
def bar():
    pass
```

The way it does this is by using `functools.partial`. The `partial` function returns a callable argument that behaves just like the function you pass it, but it will add in the extra arguments you pass to `partial` whenever the partial objects gets called itself.

Here's an example:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

foo("hi", "there") # prints "hi there"

bar = partial(foo, "bar")
bar("quux") # prints "bar quux"

baz = partial(foo, arg2="baz")
baz("hmm") # prints "hmm baz"
```

The decorator syntax using `@decorator` passes the function that is defined on the next line as a single argument to the decorator. But if you *call* something on the decorator line, the function gets passed to the return value of the call instead. So:

```
@debug
def foo():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = debug(foo)
```

Whereas:

```
@debug(prefix="foo")
def foo():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
deco = debug(prefix="foo") # this is partial(debug, prefix="foo")

@deco
def foo():
    pass
```

Which thanks to `partial` is equivalent to:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = debug(foo, prefix="foo")  # passing both arguments here, that's not normally possible!
```