# Unexpected result when changing list of functions (lambda)

Tags: python, lambda, functools

I have a list of functions each of these takes a parameter.

I want to use a function of a library which takes functions but expects them to have no parameters.

So I want to create a list of new functions using lambda to pass the param "externally"

**However the new list of functions doesn't yield the expected result.**

(This is some minimal example)

```
def fun_a(param):
    print("a")
    
def fun_b(param):
    print("b")
    

def do_something(funs):
    funs_out = []
    for fun in funs:
        funs_out.append(lambda: fun(0))
        
    return funs_out
        
   
funs = [fun_a,fun_b]

funs[0](0) # prints a
funs[1](0) # prints b

funs_changed = do_something(funs)
#funs_changed = [lambda: f(0) for f in funs]
    
funs_changed[0]() # prints b ??? expected a
funs_changed[1]() # prints b
```

I tried `funs_changed = [lambda: f(0) for f in funs]` before as it seems more pythonic, and then tried to use more explicit code (raw for loop) to find the root cause but without success.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functools.partial:

```
from functools import partial


def fun_a(param):
    print("a")
    
def fun_b(param):
    print("b")
    

def do_something(funs):
    funs_out = []
    for fun in funs:
        funs_out.append(partial(fun, 0))
        
    return funs_out
        
   
funs = [fun_a, fun_b]

funs[0](0)   # prints a
funs[1](0)   # prints b

funs_changed = do_something(funs)
# funs_changed = [partial(fun, 0) for f in funs]
    
funs_changed[0]() # prints a
funs_changed[1]() # prints b
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does):

> Roughly, partial does something like this (apart from keyword args
> support etc):
>
> ```
> def partial(func, *part_args):
>     def wrapper(*extra_args):
>         args = list(part_args)
>         args.extend(extra_args)
>         return func(*args)
>
>     return wrapper
> ```

Comment: it doesnt explain why the example in the question does not work?

Comment: Can you give a statement about @Jocker 's answer? which solution should I use, which one is more understandable/more pythonic?

Comment: For this use case, I find `functools.partial` easier to understand than `lambda`, which, as you discovered was a bit tricky to pin down. It is especially true when you are reading other people's code. In many other cases, `lambdas` are perfectly fine... but that is only my opinion, maybe others will disagree.

Answer (score 2):

just use value hack:

```
funs_changed = [lambda f=f: f(0) for f in funs]
```

it would be OK and produce an output of:

```
a
b
a
b
```

Also there is a solution for your initial variant of the code: just patch do_something function if you prefer keep it as function to avoid in-line lamda-list comprehention in main code contex (we'll do it in function):

```
def do_something(funs):
    funs_out = [lambda f=f: f(0) for f in funs]
    return funs_out
```

Comment: but why the other option doesnt work?

Comment: could you elaborate your answer or can you point me to some explanation? I want to understand your solution/my mistake.

Comment: Yes. Please look for further info here: https://docs.python.org/3.9/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result