# Looping though a list trying to create an dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of data example:

```
res = { 'results': [
{'consumption': 0.025, 'interval_start': '2021-06-27T00:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-27T00:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.043, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T23:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-27T00:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.053, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T23:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T23:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.056, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T22:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T23:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.031, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T22:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T22:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.129, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T21:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T22:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.19,  'interval_start': '2021-06-26T21:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T21:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.164, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T20:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T21:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.145, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T20:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T20:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.213, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T19:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T20:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.167, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T19:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T19:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.333, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T18:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T19:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.133, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T18:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T18:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.211, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T17:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T18:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.135, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T17:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T17:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.158, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T16:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T17:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.073, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T16:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T16:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.077, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T15:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T16:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.125, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T15:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T15:30:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.201, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T14:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T15:00:00+01:00'},
{'consumption': 0.043, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T14:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T14:30:00+01:00'},
] }
```

What I would like to do is loop though the data above and creating a dictionary data structure, an example of what Im trying to create is:

```
{
  "2021": {
    "06": {
      "01": [
        {
          "interval_start": "23:00",
          "interval_end": "23:30",
          "consumption": "0.021"
        },
        {
          "interval_start": "22:30",
          "interval_end": "23:00",
          "consumption": "0.021"
        }
      ],
      "02": [
        {
          "interval_start": "23:00",
          "interval_end": "23:30",
          "consumption": "0.021"
        },
        {
          "interval_start": "22:30",
          "interval_end": "23:00",
          "consumption": "0.021"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The code which I have written to do this is:

```
main_obj = {}
for i in res['results']:    
    
    date = i["interval_start"].split("T")[0].split("-")

    
    insert_obj = {
        "interval_start" : i['interval_start'],
        "interval_end": i["interval_end"],
        "consumption": i["consumption"]
        
    }
    
    main_obj[date[0]] = {}
    main_obj[date[0]][date[1]] = {}
    main_obj[date[0]][date[1]][date[2]] = []
    
    main_obj[date[0]][date[1]][date[2]].append(insert_obj)
    
     
print(main_obj)
```

Where `res['results']` is the list of Dicts above. When I print this out I am getting:

```
{
    '2021': {
        '06': {
            '26': [{
                'interval_start': '2021-06-26T14:00:00+01:00',
                'interval_end': '2021-06-26T14:30:00+01:00',
                'consumption': 0.043
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The question I am stuck on is why when I looping through each dict is this not getting added to the list `main_obj[date[0]][date[1]][date[2]]`? Also, as dicts have unique keys why am I only seeing an insert for the 26 and not the 27? Which is at index 0?

Any help would be appreicated as I have been scratching my head with this for a while now!

Comment: If you are working on larger data or have multiple manipulations, you might wanna look at `pandas` library.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting any existing dicts/lists with the unconditional assignments like `main_obj[date[0]] = {}`; if `date[0]` has already been seen, you are erasing whatever previous data there was.

Use the `setdefault` method instead. (I'm not sure what the PEP-8-approved line-splitting for this looks like.)

```
(main_obj
  .setdefault(date[0], {})
  .setdefault(date[1], {})
  .setdefault(date[2], [])
).append(insert_obj)
```

Comment: There was one missing `)`. I *really* dislike explicit line continuations, and PEP-8 explicitly calls out the use of implicit line breaking inside parentheses over backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner said, the issue here is that in every iteration of the loop you're overriding the existing value associated with a certain dictionary key, if there is an existing value associated with that key.

Here's a funky solution to this, using `functools.partial` and `collections.defaultdict` instead of the `setdefault` method of a regular dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
from pprint import pprint

results_list = [
    {'consumption': 0.025, 'interval_start': '2021-06-27T00:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-27T00:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.043, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T23:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-27T00:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.053, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T23:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T23:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.056, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T22:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T23:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.031, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T22:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T22:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.129, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T21:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T22:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.19, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T21:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T21:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.164, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T20:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T21:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.145, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T20:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T20:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.213, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T19:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T20:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.167, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T19:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T19:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.333, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T18:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T19:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.133, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T18:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T18:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.211, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T17:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T18:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.135, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T17:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T17:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.158, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T16:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T17:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.073, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T16:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T16:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.077, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T15:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T16:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.125, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T15:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T15:30:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.201, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T14:30:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T15:00:00+01:00'},
    {'consumption': 0.043, 'interval_start': '2021-06-26T14:00:00+01:00', 'interval_end': '2021-06-26T14:30:00+01:00'},
]

main_obj = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, partial(defaultdict, list)))

for i in results_list:    
    
    date = i["interval_start"].split("T")[0].split("-")    
    
    insert_obj = {
        "interval_start" : i['interval_start'],
        "interval_end": i["interval_end"],
        "consumption": i["consumption"]
        
    }

    main_obj[date[0]][date[1]][date[2]].append(insert_obj)

pprint(main_obj)  # Expected result (I think!)
```

The documentation for `defaultdict` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and you can read more about how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5900634/13990016). When instantiating a defaultdict, the function passed to create the default has to take 0 arguments, so it's necessary to use `functools.partial` to modify the functions here so that they take fewer arguments than they would usually. The documentation for `functools.partial` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), and you can read more about how *it* works here: [How does functools partial do what it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does).