# Passing variable to external module from tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just writing a small GUI for data analysis purposes and I thought it would be a good idea to have one file for the GUI-stuff with tkinter and the functional stuff in another file. However, somehow I am not able to pass the correct value to the module where the functions are located. Simplified version of the problem:
One file is the GUI.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

import readBinary as rb

import functools as ft

filename = "EXTERNAL"

def mytest():
    global filename
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Binary Data", "*.bin"),("All files", "*.*")))
    print(filename)

def printtest():
    global filename
    print(filename)

def gui():
    global filename
    root = tk.Tk()
    openB = tk.Button(master=root,text="File",command=mytest)
    openB.pack()
    printB = tk.Button(master=root,text="Print",command=printtest)
    printB.pack()
    #filename = "INTERNAL"
    test = tk.Button(master=root,text="Test",command=ft.partial(rb.doIt,filename))
    test.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

And the other file, in this case named readBinary.py:

```
def doIt(filename):
    print(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

The problem is now:

- using the printtest and the imported doIt-function it prints "EXTERNAL", which is clear.
- when the mytest() is called and a file is choosen, it prints the path of this file. Also when I call the printtest now it prints the path. but the imported doIt still prints "EXTERNAL"
- on the other hand, when I uncomment the filename = "INTERNAL" in the gui()-function both, the printtest and the imported doIt print "INTERNAL"

So the argument pass seems to work AND the filename from the choosen file is accessible from the gui()-function. So how is it possible that the combination gives the wrong result?

Comment: You are assuming `partial(rb.doIt,filename)` will use update value of `filename` each time it is called. But that is not the case. See [How does functools partial do what it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your use of `partial` is not how you intended to use, here is a small fix that will achieve your intended behavior.

Instead of passing the value of `filename` when using `partial`, you have to pass a reference of object from which you can access the updated value of `filename`. Here, I am using a `Class` object. You may wrap it in `list`, `dict` or other object as well.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

import readBinary as rb

import functools as ft


class FILE:
    name = "EXTERNAL"


def mytest():
    return_value = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Binary Data", "*.bin"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    if return_value:
        FILE.name = return_value
    print(FILE.name)


def printtest():
    print(FILE.name)


def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    openB = tk.Button(master=root, text="File", command=mytest)
    openB.pack()
    printB = tk.Button(master=root, text="Print", command=printtest)
    printB.pack()
    test = tk.Button(master=root, text="Test", command=ft.partial(rb.doIt, FILE))
    test.pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

readBinary.py

```py
def doIt(class_obj):
    print(class_obj.name)
```