# How to access a function inside a function?

Tags: python, function

I am wondering how I can access a function inside another function.
I saw code like this:

```
>>> def make_adder(x):
      def adder(y):
        return x+y
      return adder
>>> a = make_adder(5)
>>> a(10)
15
```

So, is there another way to call the `adder`  function? And my second question is why in the last line I call `adder` not `adder(...)`?

Good explanations are much appreciated.

Comment: equivalent: `make_adder = lambda x : lambda y: x+y` now, can you call the inner `lambda` ?

Comment: yeah! `make_adder = make_adder(...)`, then `make_adder(...)`

Comment: Which is, no, you can't.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You ask if you can call the `adder` function, but yes, you've done it in `a(10)` line.  In the "`return`" line, you do not *call* `adder`, you *return* it.  Sorry for being obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't call it directly as it is a local variable to `make_adder`.

You need to use `adder()` because `return adder` returned the function object `adder` when you called `make_adder(5)`. To execute this function object you need `()`

```
def make_adder(x):
       def adder(y):
           return x+y
       return adder
... 
>>> make_adder(5)             #returns the function object adder
<function adder at 0x9fefa74>
```

Here you can call it directly because you've access to it, as it was returned by the function `make_adder`. The returned object is actually called a [**closure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) because even though the function `make_addr` has already returned, the function object `adder` returned by it can still access the variable `x`. In py3.x you can also modify the value of `x` using `nonlocal` statement.

```
>>> make_adder(5)(10)          
15
```

Py3.x example:

```
>>> def make_addr(x):
        def adder(y):
                nonlocal x
                x += 1
                return x+y
        return adder
... 
>>> f = make_addr(5)
>>> f(5)               #with each call x gets incremented
11
>>> f(5)
12

#g gets it's own closure, it is not related to f anyhow. i.e each call to 
# make_addr returns a new closure.
>>> g = make_addr(5)  
>>> g(5)
11 
>>> g(6)
13
```

Comment: Worth noting: because Python 2.x lacks "nonlocal", you can't change your non-local variables as simply.  However, you can still make modifiable values using lists (I'll add an answer below showing this).

Answer (score 32):

You really don't want to go down this rabbit hole, but if you insist, it is possible. With some work.

The nested function is created *anew* for each call to `make_adder()`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(make_adder)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (x)
              3 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object adder at 0x10fc988b0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              9 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (adder)

  4          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (adder)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `MAKE_CLOSURE` opcode there creates a function with a closure, a nested function referring to `x` from the parent function (the `LOAD_CLOSURE` opcode builds the closure cell for the function).

Without calling the `make_adder` function, you can only access the code object; it is stored as a constant with the `make_adder()` function code. The byte code for `adder` counts on being able to access the `x` variable as a scoped cell, however, which makes the code object almost useless to you:

```
>>> make_adder.__code__.co_consts
(None, <code object adder at 0x10fc988b0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
>>> dis.dis(make_adder.__code__.co_consts[1])
  3           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (y)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

`LOAD_DEREF` loads a value from a closure cell. To make the code object into a function object again, you'd have to pass that to the function constructor:

```
>>> from types import FunctionType
>>> FunctionType(make_adder.__code__.co_consts[1], globals(),
...              None, None, (5,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: arg 5 (closure) expected cell, found int
```

but as you can see, the constructor expects to find a closure, not an integer value. To create a closure, we need, well, a function that has free variables; those marked by the compiler as available for closing over. And it needs to return those closed over values to us, it is not possible to create a closure otherwise. Thus, we create a nested function just for creating a closure:

```
def make_closure_cell(val):
    def nested():
        return val
    return nested.__closure__[0]

cell = make_closure_cell(5)
```

Now we can recreate `adder()` without calling `make_adder`:

```
>>> adder = FunctionType(make_adder.__code__.co_consts[1], globals(),
...                      None, None, (cell,))
>>> adder(10)
15
```

Perhaps just calling `make_adder()` would have been simpler.

Incidentally, as you can see, functions are first-class objects in Python. `make_adder` is an object, and by adding `(somearguments)` you *invoke*, or *call* the function. In this case, that function returns *another* function object, one that you can call as well. In the above tortuous example of how to create `adder()` without calling `make_adder()`, I referred to the `make_adder` function object without calling it; to disassemble the Python byte code attached to it, or to retrieve constants or closures from it, for example. In the same way, the `make_adder()` function returns the `adder` function object; the *point* of `make_adder()` is to create that function for something else to later call it.

The above session was conducted with compatibility between Python 2 and 3 in mind. Older Python 2 versions work the same way, albeit that some of the details differ a little; some attributes have different names, such as `func_code` instead of `__code__`, for example. Look up the documentation on these in the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) and the [Python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) if you want to know the nitty gritty details.

Comment: Just wondering: is `__code__` portable across implementations, or CPython-specific?

Comment: @rightfold: From the [glossary on bytecode](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-bytecode): *Python source code is compiled into bytecode, the internal representation of a Python program in the CPython interpreter.*. Jython and IronPython do have `func_code` attributes but I do not know what that contains.

Comment: "You really don't want to go down this rabbit hole, but if you insist, it is possible" This made me laugh. This was a very detailed explanation as well.

Comment: Very nice exposé of the guts of CPython.  @rightfold: shorter version of Martijn's answer is, "not portable, CPython-specific".  Jython no doubt uses Java's internal machinery, and IronPython no doubt uses .NET's C# machinery.  It's likely that there's some very similar sneakiness you could use in each one, because they're all trying to achieve the same results, but it's unlikely they'd match up enough to "spell them the same", as it were.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the function `adder` to the caller, not the result of calling it, hence the absence of parentheses.

Because `make_adder` returns `adder`, you already have direct access to `adder`. In fact, `a(10)` is actually a call to `adder(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to @AshwiniChaudhary's answer, you can emulate Python 3.x's nonlocal with modifiable objects.  For instance:

```
def counter(name):
    x = [0]
    def inc(n):
        x[0] += n
        print "%s: %d" % (name, x[0])
    return inc

spam = counter('spams')
ham = counter('hams')

spam(3)
ham(1)
spam(1)
ham(2)
```

In python2.7 this produces:

```
$ python closure.py
spams: 3
hams: 1
spams: 4
hams: 3
```

The reason for using `x[0]` is that attempts to reassign `x` create a new local-to-`inc` `x`:

```
def counter(name):
    x = 0
    def inc(n):
        x += n # this doesn't work!
        print "%s: %d" % (name, x[0])
    return inc
```

Attempting to use this produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "closure.py", line 11, in <module>
    spam(3)
  File "closure.py", line 4, in inc
    x += n
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

The remaining obvious thing, an attempt to use `global`, also fails as it tries to access a module-level `x` instead of the one inside `counter`.  (This is why `nonlocal` was added in the first place!)

One other point on closures: they're mechanically transformable to / from classes with instance variables.  Instead of defining `counter` as above, I could make a class:

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.x = 0
    def inc(self, n):
        self.x += n
        print "%s: %d" % (self.name, self.x)
```

and then use it as:

```
spam = Counter('spams')
spam.inc(3)
```

for instance.  Should you want to preserve the call syntax, Python permits this: instead of defining `inc(self, n)`, define `__call__(self, n)`—or define `__call__` as invoking `inc`, giving rise to:

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.x = 0
    def inc(self, n):
        self.x += n
        print "%s: %d" % (self.name, self.x)
    __call__ = inc

spam = Counter('spams')
ham = Counter('hams')

spam.inc(3)
ham.inc(1)
spam(1)
ham(2)
```

which shows the somewhat schizophrenic "two ways to call it" interface in the class. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this helps, but you can use the `__call__` boilerplate to simulate the behavior you're looking for. For example:

```py
class MakeAdder:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __call__(self, y):
        return self.x + y



a = MakeAdder(5)
a(10)
15
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
def testFn(Inner=0):
    
    def subFunct():
        print ('SubFunct Executed')
    
    if Inner:
        return subFunct
        
        
    print ('Regular Exec')
        

testFn(Inner=1)()
```

This function accepts one parameter which has default value of 0,
When set to True, the parent function returns the object of the inner function. The object, being a function, is callable, and is called with '()' :

```
'testFn(Inner=1)' will return the inner function object

'()' will call it
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. 
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).