# Python calling function in an function from another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to call 1 precise function in another function from another function

```
def exemple():    
    def dostuff1():  
        print('Stuff 1')  
    def dostuff2():  
        print('Stuff 2')  
    def dostuff3():  
        print('Stuff 3')  

def training():
    #want to call ONLY Dostuff2
```

Comment: So dostuff2() is a function defined somewhere above. What is the problem with calling it in training()?

Comment: wrox - python 2.0 page 79!

Comment: @Psytho Dostuff is inside the scope of exemple function so he cannot access it directly.

Comment: @gautamaggarwal The code is so broken so you cannot say anything about the scopes.

Comment: @Psytho Yep you are right but he edited. So it becomes clear now. He wants to call a function from scope of another function.

Comment: @Psytho i just forget some "def" before all "dostuff" sorry about that

Comment: Why then you  don't define this function outside and call it in exemple() and training()?

Comment: @Psytho this is just an exemple to simplify the question, my real code is a tic tac toe game

Comment: My comment was pretty clear about getting the basics onboard. Buy the book, shop at O'Reilly, Amazon or visit [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/oop/) for tutorials on this specific core knowledge.The web is literately stockpiled with python tutorials about functions, classes and objects. Make your mistakes in how to call it from subclass, meta-class, nested functions, etc. Get your feet wet..because ..when you hit tk, PyQt5, GTK or verilog... you really need that foundation being onboard! And above all... get your kicks with modules, `self` and `if __name__ == main :`. You'll need it!

Comment: ..don't get me wrong... I and many others do want to help you (with pleasure)... but you can't run a marathon if you can't tie your shoelaces or be a winner if you run the 42k in more than 5 hours. Capiche!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function example as this:-

```
def exemple(func_name):    
    def dostuff1():  
        print('Stuff 1')  
    def dostuff2():  
        print('Stuff 2')  
    def dostuff3():  
        print('Stuff 3')
    func_dic = {
        "dostuff1" : dostuff1,
        "dostuff2" : dostuff2,
        "dostuff3" : dostuff3
    }
    return func_dic[func_name]
```

Then call your function in the other function like this:

```
def training():
    exemple("dostuff2")()
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Why ":" after `print`?

Comment: Lol! I forgot to see it. I just edited his code. Sorry editing

Comment: Thx you, and sorry for all the syntax error .. but that what i wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

First, your syntax is not correct for inner functions: you must use `def` keyword as below:

```
def exemple():    
    def dostuff1():  
        print:('Stuff 1')  
    def dostuff2():  
        print:('Stuff 2')  
    def dostuff3():  
        print:('Stuff 3')
```

Secondly, this question has been already answered here: [How to access a function inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395338/how-to-access-a-function-inside-a-function)

in simple words, you can't call an inner function directly from outside, but you can do something like suggested by the answer from @gautamaggarwal.

Comment: First, sorry for the syntac error, i wrote that fast for an exemple. its not my real code.

second,  the link dont answer my question cause its call ALL the other function, and i want to call only 1 function, not all of them

Comment: Im new here and try to understand why people upvote you? you didnt really helped and just refer to the one that actually helped me.. people should upvote @gautamaggarwal not you....