# object has no attribute while trying to define thread

Tags: python, multithreading

This is the code:

```
class foo:
    def levelOne(self):
        def worker(self, i):
            print('doing hard work')
        def writer(self):
            print('writing workers work')

session = foo()

i=0
threads = list()
for i in range(0,5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=session.levelOne.worker, args=(i,))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

writerThread = threading.Thread(target=session.levelOne.writer)
writerThread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

writerThread.join()
```

5 workers should do the job and the writer should collect their results.

The error I get is: session object has no attribute worker

workers are actually testers that do a certain work in different "areas" while writer is keeping track of them without making my workers return any result. 
It's important for this algorithm to be divided on layers like "levelOne", "levelTwo" etc. because they will all work together. This is the main reason why I keep the threading outside the class instead of the levelOne method.

**please help me understand where I'm wrong**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a function inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395338/how-to-access-a-function-inside-a-function)

Comment: I don't think that's a solution for me, I don't need to return it's results. My goal is to target separately workers and writer to different threads.
Writer function writes a log on how workers are doing.

Comment: It's not a solution, it's just pointing out that what you are currently doing is incorrect. A possible solution would be to make `levelOne` an instance of a class which has the member function`worker`.

Comment: You're trying to use methods as closure. On python the method should return the function as a value like:

def foo():
    def bar():
         pass
    return bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly *dont* have "session object has no attribute worker" as error message with the code you posted - the error should be "'function' object has no attribute 'worker'". And actually I don't know why you'd expect anything else - names defined within a function are local variables (hint: python functions are objects just like any other), they do not become attributes of the function.

> It's important for this algorithm to be divided on layers like "levelOne", "levelTwo"

Well, possibly but that's not the proper design. If you want `foo` to be nothing but a namespace and `levelOne`, `levelTwo` etc to be instances of some type having bot a `writer` and `worker` methods, then you need to 1/ define your `LevelXXX` as classes, 2/ build instances of those objects as attributes of your `foo` class, ie:

```
class LevelOne():
    def worker(self, i):
       # ...
    def writer(self):
       # ...


class foo():
    levelOne = LevelOne()
```

Now whether this is the correct design for your use case is not garanteed in any way, but it's impossible to design a proper solution without knowing anything about the problem...

> If it's possible could you explain why trying to access workers and writer as shown in question's code is bad design?

Well, for the mere reason that it doesn't work, to start with, obviously xD.

Note that you *could* return the "worker" and "writer" functions from the `levelOne` method, ie:

```
class foo:
    def levelOne(self):
        def worker(self, i):
            print('doing hard work')
        def writer(self):
            print('writing workers work')

        return worker, writer


session = foo()
worker, writer = session.levelOne()

# etc
```

but this is both convoluted (assuming the point is to let `worker` and `writer` share `self`, which is much more simply done using a proper `LevelOne` class and making `worker` and `writer` methods of this class) and inefficient (`def` is an executable statement, so with your solution the `worker` and `writer` functions are created anew - which is not free - on each call).

Comment: This example suits perfectly my case.
If it's possible could you explain why trying to access workers and writer as shown in question's code is bad design?

Comment: @PeterBejan cf my edited answer. And I wouldn't swear my example solution really works as expected for your concrete use case (which I know nothing of) in a multithreading situation.