# Call a function of inside function in main file from module using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import math as m

def f1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a+b
    print(c)
    print(m.sqrt(4))

    def num(a,b):
        d = a*b
        return d
```

How to call to `num` function in another pycharm module ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the function `num(a,b)` is essentially a local variable inside f1(); it only exists when `f1()` is ran.

Just write `num(a,b)` not as a nested function and you can call it  elsewhere (if you import it properly) and `f1()` still has access to it:

```py
import math as m

def num(a,b):
    d = a*b
    return d

def f1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a+b
    d = num(a,b)
```

Comment: I wants access nested function

Comment: You can access `num()` somewhere else now and your function still uses it. I think this does what you want?

Comment: Please attempt a proper stackoverflow search too. This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395338/how-to-access-a-function-inside-a-function).