# How to get arg values from a subfunction's decorator?

Tags: python, overriding, decorator

```
def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    def inner(f):
        print(kwargs['here'])
        return f
    return inner

class Test:
    def test(self, a, b):
        @decorator(here='access/change this value')
        def add(a, b):
            print(a + b)
        add(a, b)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    t.test(1, 2)
```

How to use "t" to extract or change the value "access/change this value" from a decorator's args on a subfunction. getattribute can only help get function(self) not subfunction, am I right?

For example, I would like to get the value "access/change this value" without running function test.  Or change arg here = [original str] + "a new str"

Comment: Please post the code itself, not a picture of it.

Comment: And give an example of what you want to do. Your current requirement is unclear...

Answer (score 0):

As the decorator is applied to a function defined **inside** the `Test.test` method (hence a new one is created each time the function runs), we can't target the `add` function, but we can mess with the `decorator` reference.

```py
from unittest import mock as mocking

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    with mocking.patch("__main__.decorator") as decorator_mock:
        # create another version of the decorator, the one we want
        def my_other_dorator(*args, **kwargs):
            def inner(f):
                print(f"HELLO {args=!r} {kwargs=!r}")
                return f
            return inner
        # and make that it is this one that gets called when `@decorator(...)` is executed
        decorator_mock.side_effect = my_other_dorator
        # now that all is in place, let it run !
        t.test(1, 2)
```

```
HELLO args=() kwargs={'here': 'access/change this value'}
3
```

What happened is that we replaced the `decorator` definition by another, so that we can do whatever we want.
The sublibrary `mock` comes from the standard library `unittest` because **mocks** are very useful for testing, but as [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) is part of the Python philosophy, I don't see a problem with using it. But it may lead to very surprising behaviors, so I would not suggest it as a best practice though.

Answer (score 0):

If you change class `Test` slightly, you can do this in a reasonable simple way

```py
def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    def inner(f):
        print(kwargs['here'])
        return f
    return inner

class Test:
    here = "access/change this value" # 1. Add this class member
    def test(self, a, b):
        @decorator(here=self.here) # 2. Use the class member as a decorator kwarg
        def add(a, b):
            print(a + b)
        add(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    t.here = "a new value"
    t.test(1, 2)
```

I believe this lets you do what you want to do with the decorator, and it doesn't require deep diving into the innards of python objects like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395338/how-to-access-a-function-inside-a-function) (which might be of interest if you actually did want to play surgeon on python function objects).