# defining a function inside a function in python3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function inside a function in `python3` as

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Generate Init")
        self.set_size_request(100, 50)
        self.nument = Gtk.Entry()

        <did some work>

    def get_nument(self,nument):
      numele= self.nument.get_text()
      print(numele)
      <did some more work and define a function again>
        def get_specs(self,spec):
            numspec=self.spec.get_text()
```

resulting to an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw3.py", line 42, in get_nument
    self.spec.connect("activate",self.get_specs)
AttributeError: 'EntryWindow' object has no attribute 'get_specs'
```

I am really new to python, so trying hard for understanding the scope of self and origin of this error. Also, possibly I am doing things really funny by declaring a function inside a function, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831680/function-inside-function).

What I need is to define a function(`get_specs`) which will be called by another function (`get_nument`).

This is actually a gtk3 code, but I guess its problem with python.
The complete code, at its present state can be seen [here](http://paste.fedoraproject.org/87900/39560501/).
Kindly help.

Comment: Class scope is class scope. Function scope is function scope. They are two disjoint entities.

Comment: can you kindly explain how can I define that correctly?

Comment: What do you want "correctly" to mean?

Comment: So that calling the function get_specs from get_nument work without error

Comment: It's already in `get_nument()`. Just call it as you would any other function in scope.

Comment: but that is giving the error I have already shown

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.print()`?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
File "hw3.py", line 42, in get_nument
  self.spec.connect("activate",self.get_specs)
```

In `get_nument`, reference `get_specs` as just `get_specs`. So, try:

```
self.spec.connect("activate", get_specs)
```

It's just a function that you've declared in the scope of `get_nument`, so it's just like any variable. An example:

```
def foo(self):

    x = 34
    def bar():
        # ...

    # Use x:
    print(x)
    # Use bar:
    print(bar())  # Note: no self, because bar isn't part of self.
```