# Call a function inside of a function inside of a class in Python

Tags: python, function

So I'm having a problem with a larger piece of code where I'm getting an error message when I'm calling a function inside of another function that is inside of a class. In the code:

```
#Test program to solve problems. 

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def run(self):
        print "I will now square your number"
        print "Your number squared is: "
        print self.calculate()

    #This squares the number
        def calculate(self):
            return self.number**2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Foo(input("Choose a number: "))
    print test.run()
```

I raise an "AttributeError: `Foo`has no attribute `calculate`", but I don't understand why? Am I calling `calculate` wrong to throw this error?

**EDIT**

So I know that if I change the indentation or `calculate` it works, but I wanna know is there anyway to get it working as it currently is with `calculate` indented in `run` or do python classes not work that way.

Comment: Your indent level is off when you are defining calculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated after question edit:**

Check out this link that shows how to make a "closure" https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831750/2459730

It's what you described as a function inside of a function.

```
def run(self):
    def calculate(self): # <------ Need to declare the function before calling
        return self.number**2

    print "I will now square your number"
    print "Your number squared is: "
    print self.calculate() # <---- Call after the function is declared
```

**Before question edit:**
Your `calculate` function isn't indented properly.

```
def run(self):
    print "I will now square your number"
    print "Your number squared is: "
    print self.calculate()

#This squares the number
def calculate(self): # <----- Proper indentation
    return self.number**2 # <------ Proper indentation
```

The `calculate` function should have the same indentation level as the `run` function.

Comment: Doesn't he want the function inside the function?

Comment: No, he just wants to call it from another function inside of the same class.

Comment: No I actually want `calculate()` inside `run()`. In my actual the body of `calculate` is dependent on run.

Comment: @Flameancer OK well your question said otherwise, if that's the case then you should edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @Andrew_CS thanks to pointing me to closure. This was exactly what I was looking for. This code and my actual code works perfect now.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation level is off. You are defining calculate INSIDE of the run function instead of in the class.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def run(self):
        print "I will now square your number"
        print "Your number squared is: "
        print self.calculate()

    #This squares the number
    def calculate(self): #NOTE THE INDENTATION DIFFERENCE
        return self.number**2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Foo(input("Choose a number: "))
    print test.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you call function before it is defined. I think closure should help you:

```
def run(self):
    print "I will now square your number"
    print "Your number squared is: "

    def calculate():
        return self.number**2

    print calculate()
```

Answer (score 1):

> When you define a function inside a function then there is not need to use 'self'
> in inner function and call function after defining it.
> so you can write the code as,

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def run(self):
        #This squares the number
        def calculate():
            return self.number**2

        print "I will now square your number"
        print "Your number squared is: "
        print calculate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Foo(int(input("Choose a number: ")))
    print test.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just that you can't do that. It may seem tempting because you can outside of a class and it makes your code a littler cleaner, but within a class, you can't do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30578847)