# Python, parsing links from poplib email message

Tags: python, email, pop3, poplib

I'm struggling to extract links from email messages downloaded from my pop3 server

I'm trying to parse the body of an email message which matches a passed in subject line.  I'm using poplib module to get the emails from the server with the code below:

```
def pop3_return_all_messages(user="", password="", pop_address="", subject=None):
    pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL(pop_address)
    pop_conn.user(user)
    pop_conn.pass_(password)
    #Get messages from server:
    for m in pop_conn.list()[1]:
        idx = int(m.split()[0])
        # we use top(), not retr(), so that the 'read'-flag isn't set
        head, body = parse_email(pop_conn.top(idx, 8192)[1]) #build dict of values for head and body
        if subject in head["subject"]: #if subject matches
            get_link(body)
```

The parsing of the email is done using parse_email, which generated a dictionary for the head and body of the email:

```
def parse_email(lines):
    '''Splits an email provided as a list of lines into a dictionary of
    header fields and a list of body lines. Returns a (header, body)
    tuple.
    '''
    part = 0
    head = {}
    body = []
    for ln in lines:
        if part == 0:
            if not ln.strip():
                part = 1
                continue
            i = ln.find(':')
            if i <= 0:
                continue
            head[ln[:i].strip().lower()] = ln[i+1:].strip()
        else:
            body.append(ln)
    return head, body
```

Here is get links, which attempts to build up a list of links.

```
def get_link(body):
    def get_line(body):
        for item in body:
            yield item
    links = [] #empty list for links
    multipart_link = [] #empty list for multiline links
    for line in get_line(body):
        if "http" in line: #If a link has been found
            if ">" in line: #If that link ends on the same line (single line link)
                links.append(line) #add to links list
            else: #multiline link detected
                multipart_link.append(line) #add current line
                for item in xrange(1,10):
                    if ">" not in get_line(body):
                        multipart_link.append(line) #
                    else:
                        multipart_link.append(line)
                        print multipart_link
                        break #last part of multipart link, exit
                multi_link = "".join(multipart_link) #join up multipart link
                links.append(multi_link) #add to links
                multipart_link.pop() #clear multipart links
    return links
```

Everything under

```
else: #multiline link detected
```

I can't get to work.  Essentially I want to detect for multiline links, which run over more than one dictionary value, each line that needs to be added, upto when the link ends.  This will be when a > is detected.

I've hit a brick wall here.  I can get single line links fine, but multipart ones I'm struggling with and would appreciate some help.  Obviously I still need to clean up the generated links, but I can write a regex for that later.

Comment: a function inside a function! funky! maybe it can be done in another way?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831680/function-inside-function

Comment: thanks I had it outside as a separate function, I added it inside for this post, to reduce code comments :-)  Thanks for the insight though, but just so no one assumes this solves it, this doesn't provide any help into my actual problem.  Many thanks.