# Unbound Local Error when Assigning to Function Arg

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, scope, python-2.x

```
def make_accumulator(init):
    def accumulate(part): 
        init = init + part 
        return init
    return accumulate

A = make_accumulator(1)
print A(2)
```

gives me:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make-accumulator.py", line 8, in <module>
    print A(2)
  File "make-accumulator.py", line 3, in accumulate
    init = init + part 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'init' referenced before assignment
```

Why is init not visible inside accumulate?

Comment: where did you initialised init... when interpreter wants to do init=init+part, it should know init initialised before..

Comment: use a constructor to set the init value... ` def make_accumulator(self,init): def 
 __init__(self,init): self.init=init`

Comment: @lokesh1729 They are passing its value to `make_accumulator`, it's a closure variable. If they only do `return init + part` it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because during parsing the inner function when Python sees the assignment `init = init + part` it thinks `init` is a local variable and it will only look for it in local scope when the function is actually invoked.

To fix it add `init` as an argument to `accumulate` with default value of `init`:

```
def make_accumulator(init):
    def accumulate(part, init=init): 
        init = init + part 
        return init
    return accumulate
```

---

Read: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def make_accumulator(init):
...     def accumulate(part): 
...         return init + part
...     return accumulate
... 
>>> make_accumulator(1)
<function accumulate at 0x7fe3ec398938>
>>> A(2)
3
```

Since you declare `init` inside accumulate, Python interprets it as local and therefore referenced before assignment. (Note that I removed the `init =` part).

I am definitely not an expert about this, but got the hint from these posts : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831680/function-inside-function).

I guess someone could explain it better...