# Different functions - are they the same?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm a JavaScript slightly-more-than-beginner.

While reading the source for [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter), I stumbled upon this interesting and, to me, elegant function:

```
// alias a method while keeping the correct context
function alias(name) {
    return function aliasClosure() {
        return this[name].apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

I have two main questions:

**First**: why is the `aliasClosure` a *named* function? Is it useful in some way other than clarity? Also, is is really a closure? To me, it looks just like a semi-anonymous function.

**Second**: I rewrote this function like this:

```
function alias2(name) {
    return this[name].bind(this);
}
```

Is it equivalent? I think it should, since the `this` context is the same and it's preserved in both versions.

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: See second answer here for a great javascript example of a closure.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a name in a function instantiation expression makes a name available for stack traces. (I'm told newer debuggers don't always need it if the function is created in certain contexts, like a `var` initialization.)

I think the second is equivalent, mostly, though `.bind()` has some obscure special cases it handles.

*edit* wait - no, they're not equivalent. The first one involves `this` explicitly, and performs the lookup on each call. The first function doesn't need `this` to be bound to anything when it's called, while yours will throw an exception in that case.

One change that would make the two functions almost equal is wrapping `bind` inside a closure, like this:

```
function alias2(name) {
    return function() {
        return this[name].bind(this);
    }
}
```

Still, `bind` behaves obscurely in rare cases.

Comment: Hi downvoter - I just updated the answer because I changed my mind :)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. So the second version could be buggy in some contexts? I guess so, since it binds `this` to the moment I call `alias2`, and then it stays the same.

Comment: @whatyouhide right - I just added a little more. It's kind-of confusing :)

Comment: Additionally, named functions can also be used for recursion, no matter what variable the function is assigned to. Not used here, just a note :)

Comment: @FélixSaparelli thank you, yeah I knew of using that for recursion, just here it didn't seem useful :)

Comment: @FélixSaparelli oh yes you're right - that's actually kind-of important; Erlang anonymous functions don't have that (or they didn't, last time I checked), and that kind-of hurts.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, thank you. Still, by wrapping my `bind` inside a closure, would it work? Just by replacing `return this[name].apply(this, arguments);` with `return this[name].bind(this)`? If so, would it be different in some other way?

Comment: @whatyouhide yes I think that'd be closer, though again `.bind()` does a couple of obscure things (that rarely matter).

Comment: @Pointy Ok, that's all. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @FélixSaparelli ah yes; the replacement would have to bind it *and* invoke the return value.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment when I saw your edit, but before I saw your reply. For later reference, I was pointing out the differences between `bind` and `apply`, and noting that OP's `alias2()` would throw a `TypeError` if `this[name]` was undefined, while `alias()` would not (`alias('foobar')()` *would*).

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not at all equivalent.  From looking at the `alias()` function I think you would use it something like this:

```
> Array.prototype.strjoin = alias('join');   // make 'strjoin' an alias of 'join'
> [1, 2, 3].strjoin(" + ");
"1 + 2 + 3"
```

Using `alias2()` in the above code will not work.

Comment: Yes, that's what @Pointy answered above. Thank you anyway!