# When do variables become part of a JavaScript function's environment?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, webstorm

```
var x = "hi!";
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(x);    //prints "hi!"        
});
```

If I remove the line `console.log(x)` and replace it with `console.log('hello!')` and put a breakpoint on that line in the WebStorm, and if I try to evaluate `x`, it says "ReferenceError: x is not defined".

Why is that? Is it just how WebStorm works or does JavaScript have some sort of a pre-processor that only includes variables being used in a function, in it's closure?

Comment: Webstorm's debugger is probably operating in [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: @RobM. I have "use strict" at the top of my script as well. How does strict mode affect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript compiler examines the function, and determines which free variables it references, and only those variables are put into the closure environment. If you don't have `console.log(x)` in the function, then it doesn't need to put `x` into the environment.

For a related question, see

[Definition of 'closures'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083226/definition-of-closures/31083291#31083291)