# When is a Swift closure executed?

Tags: swift, swift2

I saw this piece of code in the Swift 2.1 Programming Language Guide from Apple

```
func makeIncrementer() -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

While I do understand how the scope of the inner function is available outside it's execution block - thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure), I can't understand how passing ***7*** as argument to ***increment()*** is actually taken as an argument to the inner function, when ***increment()*** actually points to the outer function.

I also want to know when ***makeIncrementer()*** is actually executed? Does it when it is assigned to ***increment()*** or when ***increment()*** gets an argument passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first 6 lines define a function `makeIncrementer` that takes no arguments and returns a value. Like any other function would, it's invoked on line 7 with `makeIncrementer()`.

The return value of that function happens to be another function of type `(Int) -> (Int)`. That means that the returned function takes an argument of type `Int` and returns a value of type `Int`.

On line 7, the returned value (the `(Int)->(Int)` function) is assigned to `increment`.

So by line 8, the `increment` variable now represents a function that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. Like any other function, it's called using parenthesis and appropriate arguments: `increment(7)`.

*Note*: Because the return value of `increment(7)` isn't assigned, the return value (which would be 8) is simply discarded.

Answer (score 1):

`makeIncrementer()` is executed exactly when it looks like it's executed, on this line:

```
var increment = makeIncrementer()
```

Swift is by default an eager (rather than lazy) language. You can explore all of this by adding `print` statements at various points.

Comment: I did. But I misunderstood what the playground output said. When I saw (Int->Int) I didn't pause to think that makeIncrementer is tied to a function as such and not to just a return value from that function. Believing in the latter led to the confusion. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand how passing 7 as argument to increment() is actually taken as an argument to the inner function, when increment() actually points to the outer function.

The `increment` variable actually points to the inner function (`addOne()`), since that's what you returned from `makeIncrementer()`. So `addOne()` is called when you call `increment(7)`.

> I also want to know when makeIncrementer() is actually executed?

It is executed as soon as you call it:

```
var increment = makeIncrementer()
```

Comment: Does it point to addOne() or does it point to the nameless method wrapping addOne()? I did understand the answer from @adpalumbo 's though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`makeIncrementer()` is being executed when it's assigned to `increment` var. `makeIncrementer()` returns the `function` named `addOne(number:)`.

Comment: Does it point to addOne() or does it point to the nameless method wrapping addOne()? I did understand the answer from @adpalumbo 's though. Thanks!