# How are these procedures able to access the input value of another procedure that is called within them?

Tags: scheme, racket

So the p-cons procedure takes x and y as input and returns an anonymous procedure that takes z as input (and remembers x and y?)
What I'm struggling to understand is when I run this in REPL:

```
(p-car (p-cons 1 2))
```

it returns 1, and 2 with p-cdr, which is what they are intended to do.However I just can't understand how they are able to access the values of the p-cons procedure? Can someone explain how this works and what I might not be grasping fully?
Here are the procedures:

```
 (define (p-cons x y)
      (lambda (z) (z x y)))

    (define (p-car proc)
      (proc (lambda (x y) x)))

    (define (p-cdr proc)
      (proc (lambda (x y) y)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why `1` and `2` are not lost, you can step through the expression as follows:

```
(p-car (p-cons 1 2))
=> (p-car (lambda (z) (z 1 2)))
=> ((lambda (z) (z 1 2)) (lambda (x y) x))
=> ((lambda (x y) x) 1 2)
=> 1
```

`(p-cons 1 2)` is essentially producing the procedure: `(lambda (z) (z 1 2))`. You can pass any function `f` to this procedure and it will return `(f 1 2)`. For example:

```
((lambda (z) (z 1 2)) +)                  ; => 3
((lambda (z) (z 1 2)) (lambda (x y) x))   ; => 1 
((lambda (z) (z 1 2)) (lambda (x y) y))   ; => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Scheme procedures are closures. They can references variables from the environment in which the procedure was defined.

When variables are referenced in a closure, they won’t be destroyed when you leave the scope where it was defined. Instead, they will live on until the closure still exists.

A textbook example of using closures is a counter:

```
<!-- language: scheme -->
(define (make-counter)
  (let ((x 0))
    (lambda ()
      (set! x (+ x 1))
      x)))

(define counter (make-counter))

(counter) => 1
(counter) => 2
(counter) => 3
(counter) => 4
```

Here, the `(lambda () (set! x (+ x 1)) x)` procedure references `x` from the environment where it was defined (i.e. `x` from `make-counter`). So, even though the execution of `make-counter` has been finished, `x` variable continues to live on, because it’s referenced in the procedure `counter`.

Please refer to the question [What is a ‘Closure’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure) for more information (the answer that has [examples in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36945/7655153) might be most relevant).