# Function property example explanation

Tags: javascript

I was going through a JS tutorial, and came across this example:

```
function makeCounter() {
  function counter() {
    return counter.count++;
  };
  counter.count = 0;

  return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();
counter.count = 10;
console.log(counter()) // logs 10
```

What I don't understand is why it didn't log 11 instead of 10? If we have set the `count` property to `10` and stored the `function counter` that increments `count` property, why the property is not incremented then to 11?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()

Comment: `counter.count` prints `11`

Comment: `counter()` will log `10`, but `counter.count` will log `11`. The `++` increment happens after the value is returned. If you want it before, you could write `return ++counter.count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understand the function property well. This has to do with how `++` works.

`return counter.count++;` will return `counter.count` at its current value, THEN increment it, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you very much, had no idea it was something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are using the *postfix* increase operator, which firstly returns its current value, then it increases it. You could change that to a *prefix* increase:

```
   return ++counter.count;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function `makeCounter` is returning a function, which has access to the  `[[scope]]` . It's using  `closure`. so It  is obvious it works like that.

Closure : ' When a function memorizes the data from the place where he was called from' .

Further information ;  [What is a 'Closure'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure)

Comment: I am thinking you missed the actual question.