# Why does the last character keeps on printing repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written the following to animate the text in a div, but I cannot find how does the last character gets printed repeatedly.

```js
var textClass = $(".first-text");
var text = textClass.text();
textClass.text("");
for (var i in text) {
  $(textClass).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 200, function() {
    $(textClass).append(text.charAt(i));
  });
}
```

```css
p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate-text">
  <p class="first-text">HTML</p><br>
</div>
```

If I try to the alert the value of `i` or `text.charAt(i)`, I always get the desired output, but when I try to append the same in a div, I always get the same last letter that is printed repeatedly. I cannot find where I am mistaken. I cannot the find the bug in my logic.

If anyone could enlighten me on my mistake in the above code, I would be glad to hear it.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/tp3juw54/8/) is the link to my fiddle where I tried this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make a closure

Comment: Switching `var i in text` to `const i in text` solves the problem. Then it becomes a scoped variable and not global as it dose with `var`

Comment: Thanks @Endless for the above fix, it worked (Y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've stumbled into a bit of learning when it comes to closures. When `i` loops through, and eventually gets run inside the function, it's only looking at the last character, because that's what `i` was overwritten to before the first `animate()` actually fires.

You can counteract this by manually creating a closure yourself, wrapping it in a function and passing it in, to preserve the variable at the time of the loop.

For more information on closures, check out: [What is a 'Closure'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure)

```js
var textClass = $(".first-text");
var text = textClass.text();
textClass.text("");
for (var i in text) {
  (function (char) {
    $(textClass).animate({
      opacity: 0.25
    }, 200, function() {
      $(textClass).append(text.charAt(char));
    });
  })(i)
}
```

```css
p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate-text">
  <p class="first-text">HTML</p><br>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use new [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) syntax, which defines `i` for the scope of the block (Which essentially creates a closure around your if block.)

```js
var textClass = $(".first-text");
var text = textClass.text();
textClass.text("");
for (const i in text) {
  $(textClass).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 200, function() {
    $(textClass).append(text.charAt(i));
  });
}
```

```css
p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate-text">
  <p class="first-text">HTML</p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, really helped me understand the logic behind my bug.

Comment: But why not const for the other two constants? They are not changing either

Comment: No problem @Code_Ninja. Javascript can get really nasty with closures, and the `let/const` syntax really helps clarify the scope of variables. I pretty much use them everywhere, and stray away from using `var` at all.

Comment: @mplungjan He can certainly, and I would recommend doing that, but this was not the scope of the issue he encountered, so I tried to avoid changing code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can either create a closure or use `let` or `const` to declare the variable `i` inside `for` loop which will preserve the current value of `i` in each iteration:

```js
var textClass = $(".first-text");
var text = textClass.text();
textClass.text("");
for (const i in text) {
  $(textClass).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 200, function() {
    $(textClass).append(text.charAt(i));
  });
}
```

```css
p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate-text">
  <p class="first-text">HTML</p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: i would use const when ever possible to indicate that the variable are not being changed anywhere else in the code

Answer (score 1):

Using the `let` and `const` instead of `var` you get a better scoping and do not need to create a closure. Also no need to keep doing $(textClass) - you can cache the object

```js
const $textClass = $(".first-text");
const text = $textClass.text();
$textClass.text("");
for (let i in text) {
  $textClass.animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 200, function() {
     $textClass.append(text.charAt(i));
  });
}
```

```css
p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate-text">
  <p class="first-text">HTML</p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @mplungjan for the fix, it worked and I wonder whats the difference if I use `var i` or `let i` or `const i`.

Comment: Even though OP is wrapping his `textClass` in `$()` unnecessarily, it really doesn't cause any overhead. jQuery will see it as a jQuery object, and simply return it.

Comment: It is still inelegant in my mind - there will be some cases where it does not and then you add overhead

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have a variable declaration in your script.

```
var textClass = $(".first-text");
var text = textClass.text();
textClass.text("");
for (const i in text){
  $(textClass).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 200, function(){
    $(textClass).append(text.charAt(i));
  });
}
```

Please review the following JSFiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/tp3juw54/19/