# whats the difference between closures and this

Tags: javascript, closures

I am just getting more into javascript and wandering what is the difference between

```
var myfunc = function(){
  publicfunctions = {}
  publicfunctions.function1 = function(){do smthing and return}
  return publicfunctions 
}
```

and

```
var myfunc = function(){
  this.function1 = function(){do smthing and return}
}
```

It seems to me that both doing the same thing

Also can someone explain what is difference between

```
var func = (function myfunc(){ .. do smthing and return .. })();
```

and

```
var func = function myfunc(){ .. do smthing and return .. }
var newfunc = new myfunc()
```

Thanks

Comment: One is an IIFE, the other is storing the function and calling it separately. The difference is essentially nonexistent. The IIFE doesn't take up an identifier but that's usually irrelevant.

Comment: ALthough, to be perfectly honest, I'm trying to guess. The examples aren't very clear. Are you talking about IIFEs or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Also: `var newfunc = new myfunc()` this wouldn't work. There is no identifier `myfunc`. Can you provide clear and concise [mcve] because this one has errors and is not actually clear what you mean.

Comment: You should read up on javascript patterns https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: the second need a binding of this, usually done with `new` as instance or with `bind`. it is not usable like the first, out-of-the-box.

Comment: I'd also suggest you read [What is a 'Closure'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure/7464475). These all contain closures of some description, what you're actually asking about is patterns

Comment: @Liam `functional-programming`? I don't see the relevance of this tag here. There are functions, sure but not FP, as far as I can see.

Comment: it is more `OOP`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step.

1. example: 
   a) you define a function that returns an object (careful with variable declaration - you should declare it with `var` keyword in order to scope it to your function. That objects has a single property that points to a function. Never the less, your first function is assigned to a variable `myfunc`
    
   Now, if you try to call `myfunc()`, you'll get an object with single property `function1`. Nothing special here.

    
   b) you define a function again and assign it to `myfunc` variable, only this time it contains `this` keyword which assumes you're trying to utilize this function as a *constructor*. In this example, merely calling `myfunc` produce no output since you haven't returned anything from a function. However, calling a function with preceding keyword `new` will result in object creation.

```
var myObj = new myfunc(); 
// `this` keyword now refers to myObj which means myObj can call `function1`
```

2. example: 
   a) On the righthand side is something that is called IIFE (or Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Basically means, a function expression that is created and executed, well, immediately. So `func` should receive whatever that function returns.

   b) Yet again, facing a constructor, only this time *you* actually assumed `myfunc` is a constructor when you added `new` keyword before `myfunc` execution. Creates an object to whic `newfunc` now points to and has authority over.

**Note:**
In constructor functions (the ones that you call with `new` keyword), `this` is implicitly returned and no need for explicit return. Now, if you want to test it and return something else instead, I'll leave it up to you to explore and see what you'll end up with. :)

Since it's a broader topic in itself, I recommend [this excellent book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593275402.do) by Nicholas Zakas. It really answers a lot of JS questions.