# What does closure function mean for Lua?

Tags: lua

As per the guide(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_quick_guide.htm),
which says that:

```
array = {"Lua", "Tutorial"}

function elementIterator (collection)

   local index = 0
   local count = #collection
    
   -- The closure function is returned
    
   return function ()
      index = index + 1
        
      if index <= count
      then
         -- return the current element of the iterator
         return collection[index]
      end
        
   end
    
end

for element in elementIterator(array)
do
   print(element)
end
```

What does closure function mean for Lua?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a 'Closure'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure)

Comment: Closure is a function using local variables of its parent functions. For example, the function returned in your example depends on variables `index`, `count` and `collection`.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, any function is a closure. In a narrower sense, a closure is an anonymous function like the returned function in your example.

Closures  are first-class: they can be assigned to variables, passed to functions and returned from them. They can be both keys and values in Lua *tables*.

Unlike PHP or C++, closures have access to all variables in local scope—*upvalues* (in your example, `index` and `count`, which keep the iterator state, and also `collection`) with no need to declare upvalues explicitly. Upvalues survive when code execution leaves the block where they were set.

You cannot write an iterator without a closure (or a subroutine). In your example (a simple iterator), `elementIterator` is a function that receives a table and returns another function, a closure. This returned closure is called again and again by the *generic for* instruction until it returns `nil`.

You may find this paper interesting: https://www.lua.org/doc/jucs17.pdf.